# Inequality for contests

Tags: inequality, summation, contest-math, radicals, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove that for real numbers $x,y,z\in[0;1/2]$ with $x+y+z=1 :$ $$
\sqrt{1-x^2} + \sqrt{1-y^2} + \sqrt{1-z^2} \geq 2\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Is this for an ongoing contest?  The site policy forbids answering questions for an ongoing contest, so when you post a contest problem, it helps if you say what contest it's from.

Comment: Try $(x,y,z)=(0.49, 0.26,0.25)$. You will find that this inequality is not true.

Comment: i have the problem from a book (preparing olympiads chapter) it doesn't comes from any contests

Comment: I'm pretty sure the inequality should be the other way around... Can you check your source?

Comment: i tried to use a substitution x=tanA y=tanB and z=tanC and the formula 1-tan^2(x)=(cos^2(x)-sin^2(x))/cos^2(x)

Comment: Put that in an edit to the question!

Comment: i ensure that this is the right enunciation of the problem

Comment: I believe that I've proved it with the inequality reversed.  Please check the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when $x=y=z=\frac13$ we have $$f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}+\sqrt{1-z^2}=2\sqrt{2}$$ so that to prove the reverse of the inequality in the question it's enough to show that if not all of $x,y,z$ are equal, then $f $does not assume its greatest value at $(x,y,z).$  Suppose then that $x\neq y.$  I claim that $$f\left({x+y\over2},{x+y\over2},z\right)>f(x,y,z).$$  We must show that $$2\sqrt{1-\left({x+y\over2}\right)^2}>\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}$$

This is easy to prove in the usual way, by squaring both sides, collecting like terms, and squaring both sides once again.

Answer (score 5):

Using Cauchy Schwarz, we can write
$$(\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-y}\sqrt{1+y}+\sqrt{1-z}\sqrt{1+z})^2$$
$$\leq ((1-x) + (1-y) + (1-z)) ((1+x)+(1+y)+(1+z))$$
$$=(3-x-y-z)(3+x+y+z) = (3-1)(3+1)=2\cdot4=8$$
And taking the square root of both sides, we get the reverse of your inequality, which is
$$\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}+\sqrt{1-z^2} \leq 2\sqrt{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Given that the function $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ is concave on $(0, 1/2)$, 
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{1-x^2}+ \sqrt{1-y^2} + \sqrt{1-z^2} &\le 3 \sqrt{1-\Big(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\Big)^2}\\
&=2\sqrt{2}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The reverse inequality could be proved by Lagrange multipliers method.

We want to maximize $$ f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{1-x^2} + \sqrt{1-y^2} + \sqrt{1-z^2} $$ subject to $$  g(x,y,z)=x+y+z=1$$

Taking gradients of both sides, we get, $ x=y=z=1/3$

Thus we have $$f(1/3,1/3,1/3)= 3(\sqrt 8 /3)= 2\sqrt 2$$

Check a nearby point, such as $$ f(.3,.3,.4)=2.82439<2\sqrt 2$$ shows that $ x=y=z=1/3$ is a maximizer.

Answer (score 1):

The reversed inequality is true.

Indeed, by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(1-x^2+2\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}}\leq$$
$$\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(1-x^2+\frac{1}{2}(1-x+1-y)(1+x+1+y)\right)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(1-x^2+2-x^2-xy)}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(3-x^2-2xy)}=\sqrt{9-1}=2\sqrt2.$$